# PLSQL: BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER WHERE CONDITION AND UPDATE NOT WORKING

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

My code is not working. NO errors
Requirement:
I want to create a trigger(either BEFORE OR AFTER INSERT) on TABLE1 to update TABLE1.TABLETYPE=1 column and update TABLE1.E2B2 XML Tag values to 1 (/icstable/safetytable/tabletype)
NOTE: TABLE1.E2B2 is clob and stores the XML File.
There are two issues: 1) The "WHEN TRIGGER" Clause is NOT WORKING
2) When i remove the When trigger clause , the updates are also not happening.

For all those records in the table1 where **TABLE1.AGENCY_ID=12345 and TABLE1.TABLETYPE=2**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_SAF_BEF_INS BEFORE
  INSERT ON TABLE1 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD  FOR EACH ROW 
  WHEN (NEW.AGENCY_ID  = 12345 AND NEW.TABLETYPE=2) 
  DECLARE 
  v_error_code         NUMBER;
  v_rep_id             NUMBER;
     
  BEGIN
           
   
   --Updating TABLE1.TABLETYPE  to 1    
          
      :NEW.TABLETYPE:=1;

    --updating the TABLE1.E2B2 Which is XML File stored in CLOB  
      select updatexml( xmltype.createxml(:NEW.E2B2),'/icstable/safetytable/tabletype/text()',1  ).getClobVal() 
      INTO :NEW.E2B2  FROM DUAL;
      
    
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004, 'ERROR');
  
END TRG_SAF_BEF_INS;
```

Create table is like this                   :

```
create table table1 (agency_id number,tabletype number,e2b2 clob);      

The data looks below:     
**********************************************
||agency_id ||  tabletype ||    e2b2 ||                                                        
**********************************************
12345   2    "<icstable>
  <safetytable>
  <safetytableid>E3223</safetytableid> 
  <transmissiondater>20201007105128-0700</transmissiondater> 
  <tabletype>2</tabletype> 
  </icstable>
  </safetytable>"                
22332   4   "<icstable>
  <safetytable>
  <safetytableid>E5623</safetytableid> 
  <transmissiondater>20201007105128-0700</transmissiondater> 
  <tabletype>4</tabletype> 
  </icstable>
  </safetytable>"
45226   3   "<icstable>
  <safetytable>
  <safetytableid>E3823</safetytableid> 
  <transmissiondater>20201007105128-0700</transmissiondater> 
  <tabletype>3</tabletype> 
  </icstable>
  </safetytable>"
12345   2   "<icstable>
  <safetytable>
  <safetytableid>E3333</safetytableid> 
  <transmissiondater>20201007105128-0700</transmissiondater> 
  <tabletype>2</tabletype> 
  </icstable>
  </safetytable>"
12345   1   "<icstable>
  <safetytable>
  <safetytableid>E322w2</safetytableid> 
  <transmissiondater>20201007105128-0700</transmissiondater> 
  <tabletype>1</tabletype> 
  </icstable>
  </safetytable>"
```

Comment: "Not working" is not an Oracle error. I suggest you remove this **useless** exception handling section and let Oracle raise an error.

Comment: Thanks LIttlefoot, When i say not working , i mean the updates are NOT happening. Question is why the WHEN trigger condition is not working? and why the changes are not getting updated.

Comment: Could you post a test case? CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO so that we could see for ourselves?

Comment: CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (TABLETYPE NUMBER,E2B2 CLOB);    <br/>                
   TABLETYPE VALUES ARE 1,2,3,4,5,6. <br/>  E2B2 VALUES ARE LIKE BELOW <br/>                                  <icstable>
  <safetytable>
  <safetytableid>E3823</safetytableid> 
  <transmissiondater>20201007105128-0700</transmissiondater> 
  <tabletype>2</tabletype> 
  </icstable>
  </safetytable>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table & trigger:

```
SQL> create table table1 (tabletype number,e2b2 clob);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_test
  2    before insert on table1
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select updatexml( xmltype.createxml(:new.E2B2),'/icstable/safetytable/tabletype/text()',1  ).getClobVal()
  6    into :new.e2b2
  7    from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into table1
  2  select 1,
  3  '<icstable>   <safetytable>     <safetytableid>E3823</safetytableid>     <transmissiondater>20201007105128-0700</transmissiondater>     <tabletype>2</tabletype>   </safetytable></icstable>'
  4  from dual;                                                                                                                             -- inserted 2

    1 row created.
    
SQL> select * from table1;

 TABLETYPE
----------
E2B2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

         1
<icstable><safetytable><safetytableid>E3823</safetytableid><transmissiondater>20201007105128-0700</transmissiondater><tabletype>1</tabletype></safetytable></icstable>
                                                                                                                  -- results in 1


SQL>
```

If you scroll right, you'll see that

- `2` was part of the `INSERT` statement
- trigger changed it to `1`

Comment: I am sorry the create table is like this                   : 
create table table1 (agency_id number,tabletype number,e2b2 clob);

Comment: The problem was that ONLY BEFORE INSERT was not working in my case as the data which i was checking was not there, so i used BEFORE OR UPDATE, Then the when clause also worked and the updates are also happening thanks @littlefoot for your time in this..............